# how to wrap all the results from async calls in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I have three models and I want to search the results from mongodb document and return the info with sex, race and age. But the find method is asynchronous. So what should I do?

```
Sex.find(function(err, sexModels) {
        if(err)
            alert('cannot find sex information');
        if(sexModels) {
            info.sex = sexModels;
        }
    });
    Race.find(function(err, raceModels) {
        if (err)
            alert('cannot find race information');
        if (raceModels) {
            info.race = raceModels;
        }
    });
    Age.find(function(err, ageModels) {
        if(err)
            alert('cannot find age information');
        if(ageModels) {
            info.age = ageModels;
        }
    });
    res.send(info); // this would be void coz find is asynchronous
```

Comment: Use promises...

Comment: This has nothing to do with answer but you might want to change your vocabulary a bit, gender instead of sex, to avoid having sex models in your code.

Comment: @pegla Thanks for your advice

Comment: Promises and `Promise.all()` will be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Without promise simple nesting:

```
 Sex.find({},function(err, sexModels) {
            if(err)
                alert('cannot find sex information');
            if(sexModels) {
                info.sex = sexModels;
                Race.find({},function(err, raceModels) {
                   if (err)
                      alert('cannot find race information');
                   if (raceModels) {
                      info.race = raceModels;
                      Age.find({},function(err, ageModels) {
                            if(err)
                                alert('cannot find age information');
                            if(ageModels) {
                                info.age = ageModels;
                                res.send(info); // here
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
    });
```

Comment: There is no reason to sequence these multiple queries as none depends upon another.  That just makes a potentially slower overall execution time.  What the OP really wants is to launch all three queries and know when they are all three done.  While this will likely work, it is not the idea way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an intermediary method that checks to see if all the properties on `info` are present

```
Sex.find(function(err, sexModels) {
    if(err)
        alert('cannot find sex information');
    if(sexModels) {
        info.sex = sexModels;
        checkAndSendResponse(info);
    }
});
Race.find(function(err, raceModels) {
    if (err)
        alert('cannot find race information');
    if (raceModels) {
        info.race = raceModels;
        checkAndSendResponse(info);
    }
});
Age.find(function(err, ageModels) {
    if(err)
        alert('cannot find age information');
    if(ageModels) {
        info.age = ageModels;
        checkAndSendResponse(info);
    }
});

function checkAndSendResponse(p_info) {
  if(p_info.age && p_info.sex && p_info.race) {
    res.send(info);
  }
}
```